# Not able to create folder on /home/ec2-user/MyDir/ on AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I wanted to create a folder on "/home/ec2-user/MyDir/test" on AWs but It is saying permission denied though I given enough permission to the directory.

```
<?php
$brideOrderFolder = '/home/ec2-user/MyDir/test';

if (!@mkdir($brideOrderFolder)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message']; //Error: mkdir(): Permission denied
}
exit;
?>
```

Here is my folder permission.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx MyDir]$ ls -ld
drwxrwxrwx 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Aug 23 14:24 .
```

Can't I make dir at "/home/ec2-user" dir in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Change owner of parent directory to "apache" user.

$sudo chown apache:apache /var/www/html/PATHTOYOURDIR/

Comment: Any thoughts on including sub directories?

Comment: $sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/PATHTOYOURDIR/

Answer (score 1):

i used `$sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/html/` and it worked! thanks @pranjitsingh for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make any changes to any folder or file on Linux, the application or user should be under that group.

Use ls -l for the folder ec2-user and see which user/ group has permissions to rw this folder and I am sure www-data do not have permission to r/w this folder. Ec2-user has right to his folder by default.

You can create fresh group and change owner group for this folder.

Alternately I ll suggest to 
Step1: create folder under www/ec2-user-temp/
And now php can simply create folders under this folder.
Step2: schedule a copy Command under crontab to copy folder recursively to ec2-user. Crontab can execute it at intervals you define.

Or you can create sym link to replicate folders files automatically as soon as they are created under www folder. You can learn commands from here

https://blog.bartbania.com/raspberry_pi/create-symbolic-links-in-linux/

For security avoid any php or serverside application to make changes to folders or files outside your webroot or www folder.

I hope this helps.