# How to give path in mkdir for create folder in ec2-server using php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mkdir

I wanted to create a sub folder for users under "/home/ec2-user/efs-mount-point/" on AWS using ssh command in php. I have a doubt in giving path name. Is this the correct path?

Beacause I execute my code and it shows Created successfully. But I can't find the folders under this path.

My code:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $userfolder ='/home/ec2-user/efs-mount-point/'.$value['id'];
    if(!mkdir($userfolder, 0775, TRUE)){
       die('Failed to create directories...');
    }else{
        echo "Created Successfully";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not vast in php but what's the use of the `.` in `.$value['id`? In Linux term, that will create a hidden folder. Moreover, why negate the value of mkdir?

Comment: **$value['id']** is the user id taken from the database. I am trying to create sub folders with name of users id

Comment: Okay, i think this is what you need [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170394/not-able-to-create-folder-on-home-ec2-user-mydir-on-aws)

Comment: @Franknike It's the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue.

I found that the subfolders I have created are stored in my local system. I used [Winscp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html) to transfer all local folders into my ec2 instance under efs-mount-point

If it shows permission denied to create folders, then you can use

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/mydir/ //I used /home/ec2-user/efs-mount-point
```